# Perl script is not working in crontab

Tags: perl, cron

I have a perl script which works fine, when run manually, however it's not running with cron. My perl script has following statement due to which it's not working [find from log file] -`push(@INC, '/var/a.pm');`
I don't know how to fix it, please help me out.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue?  Does your cron job have privileges in /var/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push a directory name into the [@INC](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/05/14/mod_perl.html#use%28%29,_require%28%29,_do%28%29,_%inc_and_@inc_explained) directory, not a file name. Try this:

```
BEGIN { push @INC, '/var'; }; ## use BEGIN so we can "use" modules
## now this will work
use a;
```

If that doesn't work, you will need to be more descriptive about the error that you are receiving.

Comment: Many times "use" is not working in cron, while "require" works. why is that so ?

Comment: "use" is done at compile time so you'd have to build the @INC array inside a BEGIN block before you "use" anything.

Comment: Hey I tried it, but no success. Previously it was :- `push(@INC, '/var/a.pm');` now i changed to - `BEGIN { push(@INC,'/var'); };
use a;`.....it's not working in cron. I'm getting below error -`Can't locate a.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /var/a.pl line 11.
BEGIN failed`.

Comment: May be some issue with PATH variable ? do i need to set PATh also in cron ? I dont have any idea, just a guess.

Comment: "/var/a.pl line 11"? Do you have a file named /var/a.pm? Why are you trying to "use a;" from a.pl? Anything in a.pl would already be imported into a.pl.

Answer (score 0):

The `lib` module will construct`@INC` for you. Add it before you load modules:

```
use lib qw(/var);
use a;
```

But, if I have a lot of cron scripts that want to use the same dir, I also employ `PERL5LIB` in crontab. This is handy when I don't want to change the source (likely because it's a vendor thing):

```
PERL5LIB=/var

*/5 * * * * perl script.pl
```

Also:

```
*/5 * * * * env PERL5LIB=/var script.pl
```

See also [How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-(@INC)-at-runtime?)